# What software options are available for prototyping and creating C++ or C# desktop app GUIs?

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface, prototype, desktop-application

I am looking for a program that will allow me to easily create GUIs for desktop applications written in C++ or C#. This software will allow me to :

- import image files or Photoshop files
- add animated effects that will be triggered by mouse events like:

  - fade in/out
  - slide
  - scale
  - hue change
- test my prototype GUI via a testing mode
- easily import my GUI into a C++ or C# program

Any ideas?

Comment: As a note: Bosses will view working prototypes that LOOK like a finished product, to be very close to completion. Don't give them the wrong idea, that's why I use paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your looking for something to create really graphical interfaces, check out WPF and using Microsoft Expression Blend.
http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx

Comment: Its nice but its pricey so is there a free solution?

Comment: thats pretty much the standard to creating WPF applications. You don't have to use Blend to create nice interfaces. You can still create the interfaces using Visual Studio, which has a free express version. Blend basically is a photoshop type interface that creates the XAML code to create the UI and graphics. You can do it without blend but it will be more difficult. You said photoshop, but if you have Illustrator, there is an Illustrator to XAML export if you are interested in anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not going for mockup but for real-gui I would suggest that you use Visual Studio and create forms with it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about c++ or c# support, but http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups seem to quite functional in mimicking a GUI, while still making it quite clear that the GUI is a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you also the Qt framework. It has a suite of cross-platform libraries that allow you to make rapid prototyping with the UI designer and incorporate easily some predefined functionalities and effects.

http://www.qt.io/qt-framework/